Questions about use software Power and Sample Size Calculation
I am calculating the sample size for the risk ratio of falls between two groups using Power and Sample Size Calculation. This is the page of this software.
In an independent, prospective setting, I need to enter Relative risk of failure for experimental subjects relative to controls (R).
What does the Relative risk of failure here mean?
For example, the rate of fall improvement is 0.3 in the control group and 0.5 in the intervention group.
Does the ratio here mean 0.5/0.3, or (1-0.5) / (1-0.3)?

This is a screenshot of its documentation：


I would guess, if probability of outcome for control is 0.3, and you think probability of outcome for experiment is 0.15, then the relative risk is 0.5. But I dunno. Is there documentation for the calculator?

Sorry ＠Alex J. I remember adding the link, but it seems that it didn't work. Now I added the software page, the software's instruction page and the software's help documentation screenshot (Unfortunately, there is very little information in this help document.) to my post. I have the same guess as you. According to this guess, it should be relative risk of outcome. But the author used relative risk of failure. This is an expression I am not familiar with. I am worried that I may have misunderstood it because of my lack of knowledge.


Does the ratio here mean 0.5/0.3, or (1-0.5) / (1-0.3)?

Whichever one it is that you want to estimate. In contrast to odds ratios, relative risks do not keep the same variance when you switch which outcome value is 1 and which is 0.

Yes, I know this. What I am confused about is that the software states that p0 is the probability of the outcome. But it asks for the relative risk of failure. Why is it not the relative risk of the outcome? I guessed the relative risk of failure to be (1-p1)/(1-p0)？ （←This might be a weird idea）. I am not knowledgeable enough and I am worried that I am not understanding it properly. Do you have any comments on this relative risk of failure? or maybe I misunderstood its meaning due to my poor English comprehension？

People don't distinguish consistently between using "failure" or "success" for the 1 outcome in binary data. Use whichever ratio you want to estimate and ignore whether the software calls it 'failure' or 'success'

Thank you very much
